# Angular Directive isn't populating ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angular-ui-router

This is my directive to implement my main menu items:

```
export class MainMenuItemDirective {
    templateUrl = "ui/Directives/MainMenuItem.html";
    scope = {};

    link: angular.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
        scope["icon"] = attrs["icon"];
        scope["title"] = attrs["title"];
        scope["ui-sref"] = attrs["ui-sref"];

        console.log(scope);
    };

    static factory(): any {
        var directive = () => {
            return new MainMenuItemDirective();
        };

        return directive;
    }
}
```

The template reads as:

```
<li>
    <a ui-sref="{{ ui-sref }}" class="button expand radius">
        <span class="fa {{ icon }}"></span>
        <br />
        {{ title }}
    </a>
</li>
```

Used like so:

```
<main-menu-item 
    title="Templates" 
    icon="fa-book" 
    ui-sref="configuration-templates">
</main-menu-item>
```

The output of the log statement contains all three values:

```
icon: "fa-book"
title: "Templates"
ui-sref: "configuration-templates"
```

This is getting rendered as:

```
<li>
    <a ui-sref="0" class="button expand radius ng-binding">
        <span class="fa fa-book"></span>
        <br>
        Templates
    </a>
</li>
```

Notice the `ui-sref="0"`.  It should be `ui-sref="configuration-templates"`.

**Question:** Why isn't my `ui-sref` populating correctly?  The other values are getting set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to access an attribute that has a hyphenated name, `ui-sref`. Try using camel case for `ui-sref` e.g.

Directive:

```
link: angular.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
    scope["icon"] = attrs["icon"];
    scope["title"] = attrs["title"];
    scope["uiSref"] = attrs["ui-sref"];

    console.log(scope);
};
```

Template:

```
<li>
    <a ui-sref="{{ uiSref }}" class="button expand radius">
        <span class="fa {{ icon }}"></span>
        <br />
        {{ title }}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: same with `attrs` which are camelCase property names

Comment: @charlietfl that's correct. However I was slightly thrown by the fact the `console.log` still showed the correct value when using `attrs['ui-sref']` which is why I haven't changed it in my answer.